# Android Studio - Empty preview and design screen

Tags: android, android-studio

The preview and design screens were working fine until I removed a part of my XML code. The activity runs fine on the emulator and my device. There's no error displayed. Anybody knows what can cause this?

I can't post images, so I'll provide the links: TEXT https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY1Ls.png, DESIGN https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI26x.png

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.akeijzer.shoppinglist.RevealFrameLayoutBehaviour"
        android:clickable="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/addScreen"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/FAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/my_recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u have to change api level 22  in this photo , and update your sdk  [image]

Comment: I'm already on all the latest (non-preview) and API 22 is selected.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?